# Minimum overhead for ASP.NET MVC authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, authentication

I want to keep things as simple as possible and I don't want a complicated security mechanism. Basically I need for a user an ID and an e-mail address and I really don't want to bother about other things. Also, I was a minimum overhead in terms of security (if there is anoter provider who can do it for me, that's even better).

What is the simplest way to do this? I was thinking about incorporating LiveID or OpenID by I don't know what are the advantages/disadvantages.

I am working with the Azure SDK.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Windows Azure Access Control Service, you can basically *outsource* all identity management. Take a look at the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78) - there's a lab called "Introduction to the AppFabric Access Control Service 2.0" that will get you up and running quickly. Currently, you can choose any combination of the following identity providers:

- WS-Federation
- Facebook
- Windows Live ID
- Google
- Yahoo!

Answer (score 2):

"Simple" for whom?

The simplest strategy for *you* would probably be to use ASP.NET's standard SQL-based authentication provider. You just run a script against your database to set up all the tables, and then you use ASP.NET's built-in utility methods to authenticate. Give your user-specific tables a foreign key reference to that user's ID, and you're good to go. We've done this, and never had any trouble with it. It's a tried and well-used system, so you know you won't be introducing any security invulnerabilities by hacking your own solution together. (see [SqlMembershipProvider vs a custom solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445260/sqlmembershipprovider-vs-a-custom-solutions/5445394#5445394))

If you want something simple for the *user*, then an OpenId solution would be my pick. Set up something like StackOverflow has, where you can let users choose an account from a number of trusted providers to allow them to log in. From the user's perspective, it's really nice not to have to remember one more username and password for one more site.