# tutorial for Custom Membership and Role provider with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, membership-provider, roleprovider

i have been looking around to find some nice working example of implementing Membership and role provider. Preferably with sample code to learn from. Do you know about some page that have some nice examples??
PS i do not want to implement the existing membership provider and hook it up, i want to learn from this how to do it myself.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found following guide for this.
hope this helps to everyone else who is attempting to do this.

http://erictopia.com/2010/05/building-a-mvc2-template-part-11-finishing-the-custom-membership-provider/

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Brian Legg has written a great little tutorial about this:

> [Implementing your own RoleProvider and MembershipProvider in MVC 3](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Found this which give other way to do this:

[What is a good way to extend .Net Membership to track user logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973820/what-is-a-good-way-to-extend-net-membership-to-track-user-logins/4973884#4973884)